# Non-Deprecated StringBufferInputStream equivalent

Tags: java, string, inputstream, deprecated

I'm working with [`LogManager.readConfiguration()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)) which requires an InputStream whose contents I'd like to come from a string.  Is there an equivalent of [`StringBufferInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) that's not deprecated, such as a `ReaderToInputStreamAdaptor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation of [`LogManager.readConfiguration()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration%28java.io.InputStream%29) says that it accepts data in [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) format. So, the really correct encoding-safe implementation is this:

```
String s = ...;

StringBuilder propertiesEncoded = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c <= 0x7e) propertiesEncoded.append((char) c);
    else propertiesEncoded.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) c)); 
}
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(propertiesEncoded.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

**EDIT:** Encoding algorithm corrected

**EDIT2:** Actually, `java.util.Properties` format have some other restrictions (such as escaping of `\` and other special characters), see docs

**EDIT3:** 0x00-0x1f escaping removed, as Alan Moore suggests

Comment: Good catch on unicode encoding specific to the properties file format.  I believe this is correct as long as `s` is UTF-8.

Comment: @Kaleb: `s` will just be a String, in the same encoding Strings always use--you don't need to worry about that.  You only have to know the *target* encoding, which is `ISO-8859-1` as @axtavt said.

Comment: @axtavt: Your code will Unicode-escape all TAB, linefeed, form-feed, and carriage-return characters, which isn't right.  Those only need to be escaped if they're part of a Properties key or element, and that should already have been taken care of by the time this method gets called.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html), and be careful to specify an appropriate character encoding. e.g.

```
ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

You need to worry about the character encoding to determine how each character is converted to a set of bytes. Note you can use the default `getBytes()` method and specify the encoding the JVM runs with via `-Dfile.encoding=...`

Comment: This won't work. `readConfiguration()` passes the stream to `Properties#load(InputStream)`, and that method expects the stream to be `ISO-8859-1`, not `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 5):

See [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

```
String s = "test";
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Comment: This won't work. `readConfiguration()` passes the stream to `Properties#load(InputStream)`, and that method expects the stream to be `ISO-8859-1`, not `UTF-8`.

Comment: Then he can pass the ISO-8859-1 encoding to getBytes()